# Como Configurar nginx con laravel para que no muestre los archivos

Tags: laravel, nginx

Como bien todos sabemos,  Apache tiene los .htaccess, me estoy mudando a nginx y tengo un problema.

mi sistema funciona bien, pero en el servidor nginx me muestra los archivos de las carpetas en este caso las que están dentro de PUBLIC de laravel.

esto no pasa con apache. pero con nginx si.

cual es la configuración correcta para que esto no suceda en nginx ?

Capture -> [image: muestra los archivos dentro de la carpeta JS IGUAL Sucede con css, image, storage]

Gracias ! 
Laravel 5.6  nginx 1.12.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

la opción en el `nginx.conf` es

```
autoindex on;
```

cambiarlo a

```
autoindex off;
```

luego un `service nginx restart` y toma la configuración

Comment: Ha funcionado perfecto :D Muchas gracias ! dure horas googleando pero nada ! y esta línea estaba delante de mi :D   Vamos aprendiendo cada dia mas :D  Un abrazo exitos.. 

Nuevo en nginx !